# Enable select option when checkbox is clicked

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm new to angular2. I need to enable select option only when my checkbox is clicked.

Form:

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users">
   <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="switch" (click)="toggleSwitch(user.id, $event)"></td>
   <td>
       <select id="intensity" (change)="toggleOption(user.id, $event)" [disabled]="butDisabled">
           <option *ngFor="let int of intensity" [value]="int" >{{int}}</option>
       </select>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Component:

```
export class UsersComponent {
    butDisabled: boolean = true;
}
```

As I told I am new to angular 2 I am not able to find proper code to disable/enable select option based on a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Using [(ngModel)]="user.check" in checkbox and [disabled]="!user.check" in select solved the issue.

It was answered by other user but unfortunate the answer has been deleted by the user

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users">
     <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="switch" [(ngModel)]="user.check"
               (click)="toggleSwitch(user.id, $event)">
      </td>
      <td>
         <select id="intensity" (change)="toggleOption(user.id, $event)" [disabled]="!user.check">
             <option *ngFor="let int of intensity" [value]="int" >{{int}}</option>
         </select>
      </td>
</tr>
```